# how can I set the tint color of right UIBarButtonItem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I'm adding a right bar button to my navigation controller with the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(
        image: UIImage(named: "settings"),
        style: .plain,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(sayHello(sender:))
    )

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = b
```

my `settings` png file is white, but when I run the app, I see it in default `blue` color. Anyway, I want to change it to red. How can I do it?

I tried this:

```
let navigationBarAppearnce = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearnce.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

but it didn't work. What's the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController() //not how you should actually get it, but just for purpose of example
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

**Edit:**

I actually use the following:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: @user3766930 Sorry, I mistyped, check my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad(), after your button setup code, add:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```